# Select a cell based on user different cell selection

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a code to automatically open Outlook and create a default email based on what is read on a Excel sheet. I am having trouble selecting a cell based on what the user selects. Example: The user select cell G2 - The vba code read the D2 cell content and put in a variable. Same for E2, C2, but on different variables. Here is my code:

```
Sub email_Antecip()

Dim OutlookApp As Object
Dim OutlookMail As Object
Dim email As Range
Dim data As Range
Dim valor As Range

Set email = Selection
Set valor = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1").Range('this is where I need to insert the instructions')
Set data = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1").Range('more instructions here')

Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutlookMail
    .to = email
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Antecipação"
    .Body = "Você possui um valor de R$ " & valor & " até o dia " & data
    .Attachments
    .Display

End With

Set OutlookMail = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Just wondering, what is it not doing as-is?  Is it not producing the results or giving you an error message?

Comment: If I set as "D2" on both Ranges, it works perfectly, but I need a selection based on variable "email".

Comment: I'm guessing you want to define `valor` and `data` in relation to `email`? However, am not clear how exactly - you might need `Offset`.

Comment: Thats exactly what I need, SJR.

Comment: Perhaps `Set valor =email.offset(0,2)` but I'm not exactly clear what is the relationship.

Comment: It will read the "email" content, and match with the "data" and "value" on the same row. The full content will be sent by e-mail.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow - that sounds rather vague, but Offset appears to be the way to go.

Comment: @SJR Offset worked like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for being vague. I will try to explain again: If the user click on cell G2, the code will read the content of the cell D2 and C2. This content will be put together on a e-mail. If the user click on cell G15, it will read the cells D15 and C15.. and so on.

Comment: Ok, so `Set valor =email.offset(0,-3)` and `Set data =email.offset(0,-4)`

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here.
Option 1 - use a relative address from the selected cell
Option 2 - Pick the row from the selected cell and set the column specifically

Something like this:

```
Sub email_Antecip()
    Dim email As Range
    Dim data As Range
    Dim valor As Range

    Set email = Selection
    ' Option 1
    Set valor = email.Offset(0, -2)
    Set data = email.Offset(0, -3)

    ' Option 2
    Set valor = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1").Cells(email.Row, 4)
    Set data = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1").Cells(email.Row, 5)
    ' ...
```